Stripe Webhooks implementation and Metadata - No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload
I am currently using a server in Node. I am implementing Stripe to manage subscription payments, but I am unable to make the requests successful.
I always get the error:

No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload. Are you passing the raw request body you received from Stripe? If a webhook request is being forwarded by a third-party tool, ensure that the exact request body, including JSON formatting and new line style, is preserved

Could it be that I am not using the correct whsec? In the example Stripe provides, it gives a whsec, but when checking if the webhook is working correctly, a different one appears.
Second Signing secret
I'll leave the code of my backend server:
index.js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const express = require('express');
const serviceAccount = require("./credentials.json");
const cors = require('cors');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

dotenv.config();

const app = express();

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: process.env.URL
});

app.use(cookieParser(process.env.TOKEN_SECRET));
app.use(cors({
  origin: true,
  credentials: true
}));

app.use('/api', require('./routes/stripe.webhook.routes'));  // Webhook routes

app.use('/api', express.json());
app.use('/api', require('./routes/login.routes'));
app.use('/api', require('./routes/register.routes'));
app.use('/api/', require('./routes/auth.routes'));
app.use('/api', require('./routes/schedule.routes'));
app.use('/api', require('./routes/appointments.routes'));
app.use('/api', require('./routes/users.routes'));
app.use('/api', require('./routes/doctors.routes'));
app.use('/api', require('./routes/illness.routes'));
app.use('/api', require('./routes/stripe.routes'));

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);

stripe.webhook.routes.js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();

const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

const endpointSecret = process.env.WHSEC;

router.post('/webhook', express.raw({type: 'application/json'}), (req, res) => {
  const sig = req.headers['stripe-signature'];
  let event;
  try {
    // Verificar que el webhook venga de Stripe usando la firma
    event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
      req.rawBody,
      sig,
      endpointSecret,
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(`Webhook signature verification failed.`, err.message);
    console.log(err)
    return res.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err}`);
  }

  switch (event.type) {
    case 'invoice.payment_succeeded':
      console.log('Succeed')
      //handlePaymentSucceeded(event.data.object);
      break;
    case 'invoice.payment_failed':
      console.log('Failed')
      break;
    default:
      console.log(`Unhandled event type ${event.type}`);
  }

  res.status(200).send(req);
});

module.exports = router;

Also, my Stripe session does not send the metadata to the webhook. I want to send the ID of the user who is making the process. When I print the session, the metadata does appear, but in the webhook, the metadata no longer appears.
stripe.routes.js
// IMPORTS - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
const {Router} = require('express')
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

// CONFIG  - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
const router = Router();
const db = admin.firestore();
dotenv.config();

const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY)

router.post('/create-checkout-session', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const userId = req.body.userId;

    createSession({priceId: req.body.priceId, userId: userId}).then(response => {
      return res.status(200).send(response);
    }).catch(e => {
      return res.status(400).send(e);
    });
  } catch (e) {
    
  }
});

async function createSession(params) {
  console.log(params)
  try {
    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
      payment_method_types: ['card'],
      line_items: [{price: params.priceId, quantity: 1}],
      mode: 'subscription',
      success_url: process.env,SUCCESS,
      cancel_url: process.env.FAILED,
      metadata: {
        userId: params.userId,
        test: 'test
      }
    });
    console.log('Session created: ', session);

    return { id: session.id };  
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    throw new Error(`Failed to create session: ${error.message}`);
  }
}


module.exports = router

I've tried with req.body and with req.rawBody, and I can't get it to work.
200 OK
I want the webhook to work so I can update the user who just paid by collecting the data from the metadata.

Stripe has this documentation page that covers common issues that can cause the signature verification to fail.
The most common root cause is that you are using the wrong secret. If you use Stripe CLI for example it has its own secret.
The second most common root cause is that something in your infrastructure is "changing" the content of the payload that Stripe sends you. It's really common with Node.js that detects a request with a JSON payload and parses it for you. That documentation offers multiple ways to debug this and links to this Github issue with dozens of potential solutions depending on your own environment.
